# Prove that $\sum\frac{n+1}{(n+2)n!}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)n!}$ converges, using the integral test.

I noticed that $\displaystyle\sum\frac{n+1}{(n+2)n!} = \sum\frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)!}$, but how do I go about integrating a factorial?

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the integral test? It is obviously inconvenient here. :)

Comment: You could use the $\Gamma$-function, $f(t) = \frac{(t-2)^2}{\Gamma(t)}$. But who would choose the integral test for that series?

Comment: If you just want to see how to find a primitive of that, then you may ask an independent question, for there are many way to assert the convergence without the integral test.

Comment: $n+1<n+2$ and convergence comes out immediately due to Maclaurin series of $e^x$

Comment: With the exact value of the sum in surplus: $$\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)\cdot n!}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(n+2)(n+1)-(n+2)+1}{(n+2)!}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}=\mathrm e-1.$$

Comment: @Did, Wolfram does not agree.

Comment: @Ivan Does not it? Then WA is wrong... :-)

Comment: @Ivan You know, the $<$ in your answer was all right... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If integral test is not a must, I'll always try the ratio test when there is a factorial. Let the sequence $(a_n)$ be defined by

$$a_n = \frac{(n+1)^2}{(n+2)!} \text{ for } n \geq 1$$

Then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+2)^2}{(n+3)!} \cdot \frac{(n+2)!}{(n+1)^2} = \left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n+3} \rightarrow 1 \cdot 0 = 0$$

Therefore the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)n!}\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2n}{n \cdot n(n-1)} \le \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{2n}{\frac{1}{2}n^3}=4 \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}<\pi^2.
$$

Comment: the OP is actually asking for a solution using the integral test for convergence...so you could use that for example in your last step (your answer would then at least use the criterion which was asked for +1)

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{(n+2)n!}  \leq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n |_{x=1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n |_{x=1}}{n!} -1 = e^x|_{x=1}-1 =e-1$$

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the integral test, but maybe it's interesting to note that from $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^{x}
 $$ we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^{x}-1
 $$ then $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}=xe^{x}-x
 $$ then if we differentiate $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(n+1\right)x^{n}}{n!}=e^{x}+xe^{x}-1
 $$ thus $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(n+1\right)x^{n+1}}{n!}=xe^{x}+x^{2}e^{x}-x
 $$ and now if we integrate from $0
 $ to $1
 $ we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}dx=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{n!\left(n+2\right)}=\int_{0}^{1}\left(xe^{x}+x^{2}e^{x}-x\right)dx=e-\frac{3}{2}.
 $$

Comment: As arrived at, more simply, in a comment to the main question.

Comment: @Did I hadn't read all the comments, thanks.